# To test the convergence of the series whose nth term is $\frac{n!}{(2n)!}x^{n}, x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I used this extension of D' Alembert's ratio test:
If $\sum u_{n}$ be a positive term series such that $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{u_{n}}{u_{n+1}} = +\infty $ then $\sum u_{n}$ converges. 
But the answer of the sum has two conditions for $x$ where the series converges for $x<4$ and diverges for $x\geq4 $. How to get this answer?

Comment: Are you sure about the series ? Seems to me that the series converges $\forall \hspace{0.1cm}x > 0$

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{4^n}{2n\choose n}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}}}$. See for instance [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals). With a $(n!)^2$ in numerator, your question would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{n!}{(2n)!}x^{n}$ is a power series we need to establish [Radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) of the series

Which is easily computable as it is

$$r =\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} |\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}|$$

So what we have to compute is $$\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} | \frac{\frac{n!}{(2n)!}}{\frac{(n+1)!}{(2n+2)!}} | = \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n}{(2n)!} \cdot \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!} = \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{n+1} = +\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

You can find the radius of convergence which is given by

$$ \dfrac{1}{R}=\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}(\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}) $$ because the limits exists

So your radius is actually $$ + \infty $$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution: Since $x>0$ and
$$\frac{n!}{(2n)!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)\cdots(2n)}<\frac{1}{n!}\,,$$
for all $n>0\,$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!x^n}{(2n)!}<\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x\,.$$